# Sum using Index vba excel

Tags: excel, vba

Can someone tell me the correct syntax for this code I am trying to execute? From a 1D range of string values, I want to pick a certain string say "this" and calculate the sum of all the values of "this" which are displayed in the immediate next column. It's been eating my head up for hours. And also, is there another better way to do it?

```
With Application.WorksheetFunction
   Range("AA2").Value = .Sum(.Index(ws(1).Range("F8"), .Match(ws(1).Range("AA1"), ws(1).Range("E8:E16"), 0), 0) **:** .index(ws(1).Range("F16"), .Match(ws(1).Range("AA1"), ws(1).Range("E8:E16"), 0), 0)
End With
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are trying to program a "conditional sum" (that is, if a cell in column A has the string "this" then sum the value of column B on the same row, else sum 0); am I correct?

Comment: You have to take a look at SUMIFS() Worksheet function (example: http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/microsoft-office/use-sumifs-to-sum-by-multiple-conditions-in-excel/ ) Rgds,

Comment: @Barranka Yes, this is what I want to execute. How should I go about it ?

Comment: @Alex Yes I'll go through the link.

Comment: Sure, it could help. Also, you can complete the same task using VBA solution as an alternative to Excel Worksheet functions. Rgds,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In excel it would be:

```
=SUMIF(E8:E16,"=this",F8:F16)
```

So in your macro try:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub StackOverflowDemo()

    Dim conditionText As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim target As Range
    Dim sourceCriteria As Range
    Dim sourceSum As Range
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)

    conditionText = "this"
    Set target = ws.Range("AA2")
    Set sourceCriteria = ws.Range("E8:E16")

    'the above stuff would probably be passed as parameters since I doubt you want that stuff hard coded
    'from here on there's no hard coding.

    Set sourceSum = sourceCriteria.Offset(0, 1)
    target.Value = WorksheetFunction.SumIf(sourceCriteria, "=" & conditionText, sourceSum)

End Sub
```

**Update:** Refactored to show the reusability / benefit of using variables:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub StackOverflowDemo()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)

    DoSumIf ws.Range("E8:E16"), "this", ws.Range("AA2")
    DoSumIf ws.Range("E8:E16"), "that", ws.Range("AA3")
    DoSumIf ws.Range("B2:B32"), "who", ws.Range("AA4")

End Sub

Private Sub DoSumIf(sourceCriteria As Range, conditionText As String, target As Range)

    Dim sourceSum As Range

    Set sourceSum = sourceCriteria.Offset(0, 1)
    target.Value = WorksheetFunction.SumIf(sourceCriteria, "=" & conditionText, sourceSum)

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. :) It works perfectly! One off-topic question. Is it beneficial if we pass our values using variables for example-here: target,sourceCriteria etc..?

Comment: In my code above it's superfluous since they're defined in the same method; so you could just put `ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("AA2").Value = WorksheetFunction.SumIf(ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("E8:E16"), "=this", ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("F8:F16"))`.  The benefit would come if you had code elsewhere that defined the range and you wanted to pass those variables to a method that did the sum-if functionality, or found that you needed to do similar things a lot of times.  I've put a second example above to illustrate this.  Breaking it out also helps make it easier to read/comprehend.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in VBA using something to this effect:
This will search E2:E300 for the string "P09" and sum the column directly to the right.

```
Sub Test123455()

    Dim MyRange As Range
    Set MyRange = Nothing

    Dim curcell As Range

    For Each curcell In Range("E2:E300")
        If InStr(1, curcell.Value, "P09", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
            If MyRange Is Nothing Then
                Set MyRange = curcell
            Else
                Set MyRange = Union(MyRange, curcell.Offset(0, 1))
            End If

        End If
    Next curcell

    MsgBox Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(MyRange)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for teaching me a new method :) It works perfectly!